# Alamofire synchronous call with lock

Tags: swift, api, alamofire

I recently start using Alamofire to use simple GET HTTP call for my project.
I need the alamofire code to be synchronous, so I decided to use lock:

```
static func recipeList(pageNumber: UInt32, numRecipes: UInt32 = 10, type: String = "order", completionHandler: (JSON) -> Void){
    var lock: Bool = true
    let url: String = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1"
    Alamofire.request(.GET, url).responseJSON{(response) -> Void in
      print("here1")
      guard response.result.error == nil else{
        print("Error: unalbe to get a list of recipes.")
        return
      }
      print("here2")
    if let responseValue = response.result.value{
    let recipeList = JSON(responseValue)
      completionHandler(recipeList)
    }
    lock = false
  }
  while(lock){}
  }

}
```

For some reason, it does not even print out here1 nor here2.

Is there anything wrong with this code? Or is there better way to make synchronous?

Thank you

Comment: What's the reason to need synchronous execution?

Comment: since my next tasks require variables in order to proceed so my code does not run without these variables

Comment: In almost all cases an asynchronous pattern is possible. Easily spoken put the code which is supposed to be executed after the lock statement in the completion block.

Comment: Alright I was looking for different qays but Ill do so. Thanks